# Get data in array after web request in Swift

Tags: arrays, json, swift

I am learning to program in `swift`. I want to load some data in JSON format (using swiftyJSON and alamoFire) in an array and then use that array in outside the function. When I print the array it is empty and printed before the output of the loop. how can I fill `naamArray2` with the content of naamArray

```
import UIKit
import Alamofire
import SwiftyJSON


class ViewController: UIViewController {

var naamArray = [String]()
var naamArray2 = [String]()

override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    Alamofire.request(.GET, "http://217.149.68.51:8080/xfind.php?userId=mike", parameters: ["foo": "bar"])
        .responseJSON
    { response in


            if let value = response.result.value
            {
                print("JSON: \(value)")

                let json = JSON(value)
                print(json["producten"][0]["productnaam"].stringValue)

                let loopCounter = json["producten"].count

                for i in 0...loopCounter
                {
                    let tempstring = json["producten"][i]["productnaam"].stringValue
                    self.naamArray.append(tempstring)

                }

                print("\(self.naamArray)")
            }


    }
    print("koekkoek")
    print("tweede \(self.naamArray)")
    naamArray2 = self.naamArray
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call request is run async so when you put it at bottom of `viewDidload` it can't assign when it have value.

you can create function call assignValue and call after request success:

```
func assignValue() {
    naamArray2 = self.naamArray
}
```

change to:

```
override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    Alamofire.request(.GET, "http://217.149.68.51:8080/xfind.php?userId=mike", parameters: ["foo": "bar"])
    .responseJSON
    { response in


        if let value = response.result.value
        {
            print("JSON: \(value)")

            let json = JSON(value)
            print(json["producten"][0]["productnaam"].stringValue)

            let loopCounter = json["producten"].count

            for i in 0...loopCounter
            {
                let tempstring = json["producten"][i]["productnaam"].stringValue
                self.naamArray.append(tempstring)

            }

            print("\(self.naamArray)")
            assignValue()
        }


    }

}
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to work. I need to call it self.assignValue and i keep the same results. I missing something I guess?

Comment: @MikeJanssen About assign I sure that you must assign after success. I can't figure out the problem of you need keep the same results?

Comment: I got it now. I can use the data now when I call the function in a button.action. THX!!